# To check transferred ethers with variable value

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

So im new to solidity,
I just want to check the ethers transferred to the contract are less equal to the value of variable I have in a contract.
It is actually checking in wei and not ethers.

```
require(msg.value > 0 ether, "Please contribute atleast 1 ETH.");
require(msg.value+Amount_Raised <= Amount_ToBe_Raised, "Please contribute correct amount.");
```

So here I want to check with the uint Amount_ToBe_Raised , but it is checking in wei and not Ether.

Answer (score 0):

1 ether is equivalent to 1e18(Wei) in solidity so you can check like this:

```
require(msg.value > 1 * 1e18, "Please contribute at least 1 ETH.");
```

Comment: No, actually  I need something like this ```require(msg.value+Amount_Raised <= Amount_ToBe_Raised ether, "Please contribute correct amount.");```

Comment: Yes, in order to check in ethers just multiply it with 1e18 or if you want in gwei then 1e9. You can do it also while declaring variables.

For example: uint256 public Amount_ToBe_Raised = whatever * 1e18.

Answer (score 0):

`msg.value` is always in wei, not in ethers, and there isn't floating point number in solidity, so you compare values in wei, or you compare `msg.value / 1e18` with a value in ether and of course you lose the precision.

`1 ether` just represents 1e18.

So you can compare like this:

```
require(msg.value > 1 ether, "Please contribute atleast 1 ETH.");
```